# Microsoft Excel 2010

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I need to change a batch of cells containing specific letters to another specific letter. The bulk of cells is so many that I would like to change it only once. Any one knows how I can do that?

Comment: Hi George, welcome to Super User. Can you say what you've tried already? Give some examples? As it stands your question is quite vague and may have a number of possible solutions.

Comment: It would be helpful to include a screen shot of some sample data before conversion and what it should look like after conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I get a few details wrong for what you really want,
but that’s what happens when you give a vague description with no examples.

> If your data are important, make a backup copy of the file first,
>   in case something goes wrong.

- It may be simplest to create a new sheet as a temporary working area. 
  If the “batch of cells” that you want to change is only a small portion
  of the sheet they’re on, you may prefer just to set up
  a temporary working area elsewhere (at an offset) on the same sheet.
- Assuming that you’ve created a new sheet (`Sheet2`),
  go to cell `A1` on that sheet and enter

  ```
  =SUBSTITUTE(Sheet1!A1, "foo", "bar")
  ```

  Obviously replacing `foo` with the text that you want to search for
  and `bar` with the new text that you want to put in its place. 
  Now, for example, if the cell `Sheet1!A1` contains `food`,
  then `Sheet2!A1` will display `bard`.
- Drag/fill the above to cover the “batch of cells” that you want to change.
- Copy.
- Go back to `Sheet1` and do “Paste Values”.
- If that turned out as you expected, you should be able to delete `Sheet2` now.

---

Oh, there’s another way.  Select the cells that you want to change
and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to invoke the “Find and Replace” dialog.

Comment: I think the Ctrl+H is the best way, no coding needed.